# Program stops working at first scanf

Tags: c

I have been working on this for a while and can't figure it out. What it is supposed to do is to determine the cost of auto insurance for each family member based on their ages. What I need to do is to be able to pass the `AgeAdd` function the family members age and possibly count (to keep track of which member it is), and it will calculate the cost and print it out for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void AgeAdd(int);

int main()
{

int age, i, o, count;   
count = 1;
printf("Enter the number of family members: ");
scanf("%d", o);

for (i = 0; i < o; i++)
{

    printf("Enter the age for family member %d: ", count);

    scanf("%d", &age); \\program crashes here

    AgeAdd(age);

    count++;
}



return 0;


}
```

once I reach that first `scanf` the program stops working, I'm confused as to why. Can I use a `getchar` there instead?

```
void AgeAdd(int a)
{
int sum1, sum2, sum3;


if (a >= 16 && a <= 19)
{
    sum1 = 1000 + (1000 * 15 / 100);
    printf("The cost for the family member is %d \n", sum1);

}
if (a >= 20 && a <= 24)
{
    sum2 = 1000 + (1000 * 5 / 100);
    printf("The cost for the family member is %d \n", sum2);

}
if (a >= 25)
{
    sum3 = 1000 - (1000 * 5 / 100);
    printf("The cost for the family member is %d \n", sum3);
}


}
```

Here is the `AgeAdd` method but I doubt there's much of a problem here.

Comment: Define "stops working"?  Does it crash?  Spew garbage data?  Does nothing and just sits there?

Comment: Why `scanf("%d", o);`, there should be `scanf("%d", &o);`

Comment: Change `o` to `&o` in the `scanf` call.

Comment: `scanf("%d", o);` is not scanning into the address of o, it's scanning into the value (being interpretted as an address).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix your first `scanf` call (you need to pass a pointer):

`scanf("%d", &o);`

Put a space between subsequent `scanf` calls:

`scanf(" %d", &age);`

This passes over the newline character entered on a previous iteration.

Comment: Thank you, it is no longer crashing. I just need to figure out why its printing twice now, but that should be easy. Once again thank you

Comment: "Put a space between subsequent scanf calls" is mis-leading.  It is true that a space in the format "passes over the newline character entered on a previous iteration", but so does `"%d"`.  The space is not needed at all.  "Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a [, c, or n specifier"  C11dr §7.21.6.2 8

Comment: I agree although in the end, professional c programmers realise the shortcomings of the stdlib i/o functions, and write their own.